# How select elements by class in IONIC?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

currently I am working in an IONIC envieronment, and I need to select an element by its class, I tried to do that by:

```
angular.element( '.nv-series' ).addClass( "hidden-chart" );
```

But in my android it returns : 'Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.
I think it happens because angular.element( '.nv-series' ) doesnt select nothing.

Thanks in advance